# Python - Pandas dataframe merge: two dataframes on multiple columns returning NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: One being a daily performance metric per VM, the other being cluster level details like how many VMs/Blade.

I'm trying to populate the VM performance metric dataframe with details of the cluster on that particular day.

df1 - daily performance metric per VM

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+
| Audit Date  |  Cluster  |   VM    |   Metric   | Peak |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+
| 2019-10-08  | Cluster A | Server1 | CPU Util % |   88 |
| 2019-10-08  | Cluster A | Server2 | CPU Util % |   34 |
| 2019-10-08  | Cluster B | Server3 | CPU Util % |   89 |
| 2019-10-08  | Cluster B | Server4 | CPU Util % |   92 |
| 2019-10-09  | Cluster A | Server1 | CPU Util % |   88 |
| 2019-10-09  | Cluster A | Server2 | CPU Util % |   34 |
| 2019-10-09  | Cluster B | Server3 | CPU Util % |   89 |
| 2019-10-09  | Cluster B | Server4 | CPU Util % |   92 |
+-------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+
```

df2 - Daily Cluster values

```
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| Audit Date |  Cluster  | VMs Per Blade |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster A |            62 |
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster B |            32 |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster A |            64 |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster B |            32 |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
+------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+---------------+
| Audit Date |  Cluster  |   VM    |   Metric   | Peak | VMs Per Blade |
+------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+---------------+
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster A | Server1 | CPU Util % |   88 |            62 |
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster A | Server2 | CPU Util % |   34 |            62 |
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster B | Server3 | CPU Util % |   89 |            32 |
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster B | Server4 | CPU Util % |   92 |            32 |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster A | Server1 | CPU Util % |   88 |            64 |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster A | Server2 | CPU Util % |   34 |            64 |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster B | Server3 | CPU Util % |   89 |            32 |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster B | Server4 | CPU Util % |   92 |            32 |
+------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+---------------+
```

What I've tried so far:
I've been trying to do a pandas merge on these using:

```
    df1.merge(df2, how="left", on=["audit date", "cluster"])
```

However when I try this I'm getting all NaNs in the VM Per Blade fields.

```
+------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+---------------+
| Audit Date |  Cluster  |   VM    |   Metric   | Peak | VMs Per Blade |
+------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+---------------+
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster A | Server1 | CPU Util % |   88 | NaN           |
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster A | Server2 | CPU Util % |   34 | NaN           |
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster B | Server3 | CPU Util % |   89 | NaN           |
| 2019-10-08 | Cluster B | Server4 | CPU Util % |   92 | NaN           |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster A | Server1 | CPU Util % |   88 | NaN           |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster A | Server2 | CPU Util % |   34 | NaN           |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster B | Server3 | CPU Util % |   89 | NaN           |
| 2019-10-09 | Cluster B | Server4 | CPU Util % |   92 | NaN           |
+------------+-----------+---------+------------+------+---------------+
```

I have attempted to convert the columns to a string and strip them to make sure there wasn't any trailing spaces to no avail.

```
df1['audit date'] = df1['audit date'].astype(str).str.strip()
```

I'm unsure if this is related but my df2 dataframe has some duplicate rows due to duplication of analysis models being used again the cluster.

Comment: I tried your example with duplicates(the combination of audit date and cluster) in df2 and it gave me multiple entries, but not NaN. And if there are no duplicates, then it works fine. Why not drop the duplicates like this `df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['Audit Date', 'Cluster']), how='left', on=['Audit Date', 'Cluster'])` ?

Comment: @vb_rises thanks for your recommendation. This cleared up the duplicates to clean up my data and I came to realize that Excel was destroying the csv that I was importing into the dataframe when I was validating the duplicate removal. Your answer helped in more ways than one!